# Run command after `docker-compose up --build` finishes

Tags: docker-compose, yarnpkg

I've got the following `package.json`

```
"dev": "yarn dc && yarn run-services",
"run-services": "for I in services/*/; do echo \"cd $I && yarn dev\" | perl -p -e 's/\\n/\\0/;'; done | xargs -0 concurrently --kill-others",
"dc": "docker-compose up --build
```

I need `run-services` to run *after* Docker Compose has built and started the containers. I can use `yarn dc & yarn run-services` to run them in parallel, but this isn't what I need. I use `&&` to run them sequentially, `run-services` never runs.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Does using a semicolon work?

Comment: @Aplet123 unfortunately not. my guess is that Docker Compose process hangs around and doesn't exit.

Comment: What happens if you run `docker-compose up --build` by itself, then once it finishes you run `echo $?` afterwards?

Comment: @Aplet123 Because the docker compose up command leaves a process running, i'd have to CTRL+C to quit the running process, right?

Comment: Ah well that could be an issue. You might want to run it with `-d` to keep in in the background so your other commands can run.

Comment: Run the first command in the background by ending it with `&` and then use something like [just-wait](https://npmjs.com/package/just-wait) to trigger the next command to run when the command in the background is ready., by watching for a file to be created or something like that. *Disclaimer*: I am the author of `just-wait`.